# multiple definition of `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)

Tags: c++, mingw, std, cross-compiling, linker-errors

I am cross-compiling a windows application from my Linux host machine and I am getting a linking error of multiple definitions between two files in the std!

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/libstdc++.a(cow-stdexcept.o):(.text$_ZNSt11logic_errorC2ERKS_+0x0): multiple definition of `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)'
/home/user1/work/windows-release/test/test.o:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/include/c++/stdexcept:113: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in stdexcept:113 I found the definition of the following class

```
  class logic_error : public exception
  {
    __cow_string _M_msg;

  public:
    /** Takes a character string describing the error.  */
    explicit
    logic_error(const string& __arg) _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE;

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    explicit
    logic_error(const char*) _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE;
#endif

#if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI || _GLIBCXX_DEFINE_STDEXCEPT_COPY_OPS
    logic_error(const logic_error&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
    logic_error& operator=(const logic_error&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
#endif

    virtual ~logic_error() _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;

    /** Returns a C-style character string describing the general cause of
     *  the current error (the same string passed to the ctor).  */
    virtual const char*
    what() const _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;

# ifdef _GLIBCXX_TM_TS_INTERNAL
    friend void*
    ::_txnal_logic_error_get_msg(void* e);
# endif
  };
```

These are my build flags

```
-g -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing  -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-placement-new -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-deprecated -Wextra -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -O3  -O -MMD -MP -MT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building the code with `CXX_FLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_DEFINE_STDEXCEPT_COPY_OPS` solved the issue.

by looking at the symbols of test.o using `nm -C test.o`, I found that the copy constructor was defined and had an address mentioned next to it, I made an assumption that the compiler automatically created the copy constructor for me as it didn't find its prototype in the class declaration because of `#if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI || _GLIBCXX_DEFINE_STDEXCEPT_COPY_OPS` and that's why by defining `_GLIBCXX_DEFINE_STDEXCEPT_COPY_OPS` the complier would know that its implemented somewhere else so don't create it!